# Can some operators operate only on Natural / Real / Complex numbers?

Tags: operator-theory

Can some operators operate only on Natural / Real / Complex numbers ?

---

$$
o_1 + o_2 \longrightarrow C
$$
$$
o_1 - o_2 \longrightarrow C
$$
$$
o_1 * o_2 \longrightarrow C
$$
$$
o_1 / o_2 \longrightarrow C
$$

---

What about:
$$
a \uparrow_{t}^{x}
$$
Where:
$$
a \uparrow_{1}^{x} = a^x
$$
$$
a \uparrow_{2}^{x} = a^{a^x}
$$
$$
a \uparrow_{3}^{x} = a^{a^{a^x}}
$$
$$
\dots
$$

Comment: Every operator is defined for the specific context in which you are working.  That some operators are given the same name and are given similar properties can be thought of as coincidence.  There are of course infinitely many operators possible, and only some are useful enough to be named.

Comment: Even $+$ is defined differently for the naturals, rational, real and complex numbers. Using the same symbol for multiple distinct operations is sometimes called overloading.